# Add custom user fields in Multisite USERS page

Tags: multisite

I use

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_func' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_func' );
```

but this functions are only displayed on SUB-SITE user-profiles... How to make them to be shown in GLOBAL MULTISITE user-profile? 
I mean, I want to set some fields for users that will be global, not only per-site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how these functions are being set up.

Most likely right now these are set in a theme file somewhere. In that case, they will only run for the sites that have that theme enabled.

I have not tried it, but I believe if you move the code that accomplishes your goal into a plugin, and then enable that plugin as a global plugin, you should get those fields added to all user profiles across the multisite.

Comment: that is in plugin, which is NETWORK ACTIVE

Comment: okay, can you add that information to the question? What is it doing right now, and be more explicit about what you expect to be doing.

Comment: I expect the field s was shown on user-profile page (for admins) in NETWORK>USERS.